# Need a debugger for Dos Assembly

Tags: assembly, debugging, dos

I'm trying badly to track down a debugger for DOS assembly, it's really hard to debug this code and I need a debugger. Does anyone out there know where I can download any version of turbo debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenWatcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) project contains a very good debugger, which exists in both 16 bits and 32 bits versions for DOS (32bits through several so-called DOS extenders), Windows and OS/2.
Have a look at the documentation [here](http://www.openwatcom.org/ftp/manuals/1.5/wd.pdf)

Also check [IDAPro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/overview.htm), a combined disassembler-debugger.  A free version is available [here](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/)

Comment: Hmm, OpenWatcom didn't work because i'm on Win7 64-bit. Can I get the dos version and use it trough dos box?

Comment: @data_jepp IMO you're going to have a real hard time debugging DOS programs under W7, AFAIK W7 is completely unable to run DOS applications.  You should probably run a virtual machine with DOS, and there you can use the Watcom DOS version.

Comment: I don't think IDA Pro will allow you to debug a DOS application. It will only disassemble it.

Answer (score 2):

The place you can download legal version of old borland tools is here:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum